# Image Upload with JavaScript and JSF does sporadically not work

Tags: javascript, jsf

i have a problem with image uploading in JavaScript and JSF:

On a mobile web page the user can take a photo with the integrated camera which is immediately uploaded to the server and stored in a MySql-Database, but sometimes the upload simply stops. I don't see a pattern when this problem occures. It works most of the times.

Here the code:

**JSF**

```
<h:form id="imageInputForm">
  <h:panelGroup styleClass="invisible">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]"  accept="image/*;capture=camera" />
    <h:inputHidden value="#{bean.imageData}" type="text" id="inputId" />
  </h:panelGroup>
  <div id="loading" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index: 5000; margin: 0 auto; width:100%"  >
    <table style="width:100%; height:100%; align:center; text-align:center;">
        <tr>
          <td>
             <img height="130px" width="130px;" src="../../resources/ajaxloading.gif" alt="" />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>    
</h:form>

<h:form>
   <p:commandLink immediate="true" onclick="onClickTakeCam();">
      <p:graphicImage height="27" width="35" value="/resources/camera_icon.png" style="border: none;" />
  </p:commandLink>
</h:form>   

<style type="text/css">  
    .invisible {
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function onClickTakeCam() { 
        $("#files").click();
    }

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        $('#loading').show();
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                  if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                    continue;
                  }
                 var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                    return function(e) {
                      var result = e.target.result;
                      var input = document.getElementById("imageInputForm:inputId");
                      input.value = result;
                      document.getElementById('imageInputForm').submit();
                    };
                  })(f);
               reader.readAsDataURL(f); 
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

</script>
```

**Bean**

```
public String getImageData() {
    return imageData;
}


public void setImageData(String imageData) {
    if (imageData != null && !imageData.equals(this.getImageData())) {
        this.imageData = imageData;
        imageUploaded();
    } else {
        this.imageData = imageData;
    }
}

public void imageUploaded() {
   byte [] uploadedImage = Base64.decodeBase64(this.getImageData().substring(22));
    //process byte array from here
    //[...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems in your code.

First one is the fact that you do not handle error when you read file using `FileReader`. You should set properties [FileReader.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.onerror) and [FileReader.onabort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.onabort). Otherwise when error happens or file reading is aborted nothing happens and it looks like the page has frozen.

Second problem is the following line:

```
<p:commandLink immediate="true" onclick="onClickTakeCam();">
```

You had better add `return false;` or use `onstart`. Otherwise Primefaces sends some AJAX request that might intermingle with subsequent form submit.

If fixing above problems does not solve freezing please provide more details what hangs and what gets executed (e.g. is the request sent to the server or not).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed to "onstart" and added an "onerror"- and "onabort"-listener, but both listeners are not called when the page freezes. I debugged the problem and found out that the "onClickTakeCam()-Function" gets called, but the setter in the bean is not called.